# Setting "Standard_Conforming_strings" parameter to "off" impact

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

As a part of DB migration, we are moving to PostgreSQL and we observed that extra "" is inserting in bytea column of Quartz table. If we set the parameter "Standard_Conforming_strings" to off, we are able to save the data in proper format. As a part of our scenario, our record uses xml file as a input parameter and we are suspecting that by setting that parameter this setting may omit "" characters which are in xml file.
Can anyone suggest by setting this parameter to "off" is there any impact?

1. WPF application
2. PostgreSQL v11
3. Quartz 1.0.3.3
4. nHibernate 3.0.4000
5. dotconnectforPostgreSQL

We tried setting the "Standard_Conforming_strings" to off and its working . But we want to know the impact of this parameter change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impact is that sequences such as `\n` or `\t` (there are more) start having a special, non standard conforming, meaning in string literals: they are interpreted as special characters (in this case, newline and tabulator).

This is a leftover from the old days, when that was the normal behavior of PostgreSQL. If your client software needs that setting to work properly, that may be because you are using very old drivers to access the database (or the application itself is very old). Upgrading the client libraries and drivers *may* help.